# What is difference between abstime and reltime in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I stumbled on these 2 data types in pgAdmin and was not able to figure out their purpose and difference between them in PostgreSql . Can some one please explain the difference between

abstime and reltime

Comment: There is no [data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) `abstime` in Postgres. Where exactly did you find that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There was. Sort of. *"The types abstime and reltime are lower precision types which are used internally. You are discouraged from using these types in applications; these internal types might disappear in a future release."* ([source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html))

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Ah, interesting. I have never seen that. Thanks. You might want to add that quote to your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`abstime` stores a date.
`reltime` stores a difference between dates.

They're both deprecated. Don't use them:

> The types abstime and reltime are lower precision types which are used internally. You are discouraged from using these types in applications; these internal types might disappear in a future release.

[source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html)

Use `timestamp` and `interval` instead, they're the non deprecated equivalents.

The `interval` data type is useful to do time arithmetic:

```
select now() - interval '1 year 2 months 4 days';
```